# Client server protocol with XML messages

Tags: java, protocols

I have to implement client server protocol over socket in java, and sending the data as XML messages, so i implement one by my self, but i want to know is there any standard API, or standard way to do this in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) is the standard. Example Java implementations are [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), [JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) and [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/).

For something a bit simpler, you might want to look at [Burlap](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/protocols/burlap.xtp), but that's very much not a standard, or [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).